# Why I am getting error at Internet Explorer 7.0 and 8.0?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, jquery-validate, jquery-1.7

I use custom validation for my field

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="region">Region*</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="region" name="region" minlength="1" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>

var regionsList = ["value1", "value2", ..., "value 80"];

$.validator.addMethod("validRegion", function (value, element, param) {
  return this.optional(element) || (param.indexOf(value) != -1); // ERROR IS HERE
}, "Please start to type and choose correct value");

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    "region": {
      required: true,
      validRegion: regionsList
    },
 ...
```

What can be wrong at this line (please look for the line with comment ERROR IS HERE)?
The error is `Object doesn't support this property or method`.

Comment: Yeah please tell the details. What's the error?

Comment: @pst, the line has been given, please look for the comment in the code. And I've added the error message.

Comment: Not the answer but just in case... when declaring an object, make sure you don't have a ',' after the last property. IE7 and IE8 will give you an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is only supported on IE 9+.  Since you are already using jQuery, you can use [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) (it will use `Array.indexOf` if its supported).

```
$.validator.addMethod("validRegion", function (value, element, param) {
  return this.optional(element) || ($.inArray(value, param) != -1);
}, "Please start to type and choose correct value");
```